# How can I reshape 1D np array into 3D?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

I have my 699 training features stored in the array X.

```
X.shape
```

(699,)

Each row is however 1292 * 13

For instance:

```
X[0].shape
```

(1292, 13)

How can I reshape it correctly to input into a CNN?

Comment: `np.stack(X)` might work.  Or it might throw an error because the subarrays differ in shape.

Comment: Yes, this worked thanks a lot. I will add this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X = np.stack(X) did the job as mentioned by @hpaulj

```
X.shape
```

(419, 1292, 13, 1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to put them in a keras  Conv2D for example, you must have a specific input_shape.

So , your number of samples is 699 and your shape is (1292, 13, 1) .
The last dimension (1) is the number of channels, so if you have gray images (or something else) you put 1 , if you have color you put 3.

So something like that:

`input_shape = (len(x), X[0][0].shape, X[0][1].shape, 1)`

`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)`